# Format an object parsed from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i need to create array from external json file which looks like this

```
{
  "cases":[
    { 
        "case_no":1,
        "case_input":[
        {
          "input1":6,
          "input2":[1,2,3,4,10,11]
        }],
        "case_output":31
    },
    { 
      "case_no":2,
      "case_input":[
        {
          "input1":5,
          "input2":[5,5,5,5,14,17]
        }],
      "case_output":51
    }
        ]       
}
```

i need to create a array which needs to look like this

```
["6↵1 2 3 4 10 11","5↵5 5 5 5 14 17"]
```

how can i do this with javascript

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: i don't know how to get inside case_input>input so far i have done something 
 "var testcases = [];
                  for(var j in jsn.cases ){
                    testcases[j]= jsn.cases[j].case_input;
                  }
                  testcase = JSON.stringify(testcases);"

which is undoutedly veryyyyyy wrong

Comment: @SahanSerasinghe tried something more  var testcases = [];
                  for(var j in jsn.cases ){
                    for(var i in jsn.cases[j].case_input ){
                      testcases[j]= jsn.cases[j].case_input[i];
                    }

                  }

Comment: An object can't have more than one property with the same key. With the object literal above, the question's objective cannot be met.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 ok i can change input to input_1, input_2 then.....

Answer (score 1):

**Your input JSON object is not valid as it has duplicate object keys as siblings (input).** 
Unless you rename them to be distinct there is no way you can get the expected result.
Assuming, you have distinct keys; here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nurzesx1/)

```
// Code goes here
'use strict';

let jsObj = {
  "cases":[
    { 
        "case_no":1,
        "case_input":[
        {
          "input":6,
          "input2":[1,2,3,4,10,11]
        }],
        "case_output":31
    },
    { 
      "case_no":2,
      "case_input":[
        {
          "input":5,
          "input2":[5,5,5,5,14,17]
        }],
      "case_output":51
    }
        ]       
}
let inputArr = [];
jsObj['cases'].forEach(function(caseInput) {
  caseInput.case_input.forEach(function(caseInput) {
    let obj = {};
    obj[caseInput.input] = caseInput.input2;
    inputArr.push(obj)
  })
});

console.log(inputArr);
```

//Output

[{6:1,2,3,4,10,11}, {5:5,5,5,5,14,17}]

Comment: it is returning [{"undefined":[1,2,3,4,10,11]},{"undefined":[5,5,5,5,14,17]}] after stringifying

Comment: Pls refer to the updated jsfiddle. It does return the expected result.
https://jsfiddle.net/nurzesx1/2/

Comment: well i tried 
 var testcases = [];
                  for(var j in jsn.cases ){
                    for(var i in jsn.cases[j].case_input ){
                     var  testcase=[];
                      testcase[j]= jsn.cases[j].case_input[i];
                      testcases.push(testcase)
                    }

                  }

                  testcases = JSON.stringify(testcases);
                console.log(testcases);

which returns
 [[{"input1":6,"input2":[1,2,3,4,10,11]}],[null,{"input1":5,"input2":[5,5,5,5,14,17]}]]

Comment: number of issues with your approach.
1] you are iterating over an object using for(x in ..) which iterates through all the properties in the prototype. you should add a hasOwnProperty check if you really want to do that. OR. simply go functional using Object.keys like I have done.

2] you are setting indexes manually in a JS array. I would use an array if the indexes are sequential and numeric leaving the array index compact. In your case, your array.length would be (your greatest index value) + 1. 

try using the stub I have provided instead.